# CakePHP Model Design Advice: Associating a RDBMS model with an extensible/hierarchical model (JSON/XML/Array)

Tags: cakephp, database-design, model, data-modeling

**Before You Continue Reading**
I'm mostly seeking advice on data modelling *strategy* as against *implementation* (though I touch on this at the end a bit)—I mostly know how to do what I'm describing, but I'm not as confident that some ways of doing it aren't fool's errands.

### **The Problem**

Broadly, I have a model (call it `Game` as my actual context is pretty esoteric) with primarily properties of known structure & size (`title`,`player_id`, etc.). Except that one property, `game_template`, warrants a model itself, but a hierarchical one—I'm using JSON, but it could be XML, whatever. Importantly, I do *not* need to query`game_template`; it will *always* be required all-or-none, it really is a property of the `Game` model except when being manipulated in the context of it's parent instance of `Game`.

**Do I Really Need Two Models?**
Though every game–game_template relationship will always be have-and-belongs-to-one, all templates should share some methods and will have common required fields (ie. a `params` property, of which there may be 0–n params, each having 0–n of fields of a variety of types)

Where I become unsure is how to link these together inside Cake effectively.

### **The Two Solutions I'm Considering (though I'm open to any)**

**1) Using "extracted" data from one model object to create the other**
Include the JSON as text a column on the database, ie. `games.game_template`. When a `Game` record is instantiated by the controller, have it also instantiate a `Game Template` model by parsing the raw text (ie. `json_decode('game_template', true)`) and passing the result as an [array datasource](https://github.com/cakephp/datasources/blob/2.0/Model/Datasource/ArraySource.php) from which to model it?

**2) Keep the data in a separate file and use model associations**
Keep .JSON files somewhere locally (say `lib/game_templates/<id>.json`) and then associate this id with the parent model vis-a-vis cakephp convention (ie. a `game_template_id` field of `game`? Intuitively I can think of reasons to go either way. If this *is* the appropriate solution, though, I've no idea if CakePHP can handle associations between totally different data sources or if there is anything beyond what I've described that I'd need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is right forum for your question?  Your question involves JSON, text on a column on the database, instantiation of a model, parsing raw text, passing results, arrays, where to store files, etc.

I think that none of these subjects are relevant to data modeling.  For me they are all design or implementation-related.

Comment: I see the confusion—suggestions for better tagging are welcome.  What I am trying to establish is how best to model the data *according to cakephp's conventions*. I guess I am really referring to Model design in an MVC context. I am trying to figure out whether I'm better served treating the hierarchical structure as just a complex property of a model (ie. option 1) or whether what I describe above is more appropriately considered two, associated models proper (ie. option 2). Thanks for taking the time to ask, though

Comment: You say that you are trying to model data according to your chosen implementation (cakephp conventions).  Mightn't it be better to do the exact opposite: make the model dependent upon customer requirements, and make the implementation dependent on the model? (I am not an expert in this area and my philosophy may not be practical.)

Answer (score 0):

The way you state the question here ('should I treat the structure as a property or a model?') *does* seem (to me) to be a pure data modeling question.  So maybe it would be better to edit the OP along those lines, and leave the tags as they are?

For me it would be much easier to think about the problem with all the implementation-related stuff cut away.  I can think about a question about classes, attributes, keys, and relationships much better if I don't have to think about tooling, programming languages, tables, columns, and protocols, at least at first.  Of course, if you have two choices of model that accurately describe the Customer's to-be world, you must be concerned to pick the one that is the best for your target implementation.  But it is hard to think of everything at once.